# Using C# properties for simple operations, where should I draw the line?

Tags: c#, linq, properties

Should I be putting Linq statements inside of an objects properties?  Is that a best practice or is that a no no?  Also if that is ok, where do I draw the line with this?  I assume db access is probably too far but is there a line, or just a gray area?  Do you see any issues with my usage of Linq?

```
[XmlRoot("message")]
public class Message
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("segment")]
    public Segment[] segments { get;set; }
    [XmlElement("group")]
    public Group[] groups { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public Field[] Issues { get; set; }`public Field[] Issues { get; set; }

    public bool HasNoIssues
    {
        get
        {
            return Issues == null || Issues.Length == 0;
        }
    }

    public bool HasWarnings
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HasNoIssues)
                return Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Warnings").Count() > 0;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HasNoIssues)
                return Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Errors").Count() > 0;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public ResponseTags[] Warnings
    {
        get
        {
            if (HasWarnings)
                return Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Warnings").First().groups.First().warnings;
            return new ResponseTags[0];
        }
    }

    public ResponseTags[] Errors
    {
        get
        {
            if (HasErrors)
                return Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Errors").First().groups.First().warnings;
            return new ResponseTags[0];
        }
    }

    public string DisplayWarnings
    {
        get
        {
            var warningString = "";
            if (HasWarnings)
            {
                warningString += Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Warnings").First().groups.First().warnings.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + t.value +"\n");                   
            }
            return warningString;

        }
    }

    public string DisplayErrors
    {
        get
        {
            var errorString = "";
            if (HasErrors)
            {
                errorString += Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Errors").First().groups.First().errors.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + t.value+"\n");
            }
            return errorString;

        }
    }}

[Serializable]
public class Segment
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public Field[] fields { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Group
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("segment")]
    public Segment[] segments { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("e")]
    public ResponseTags[] errors { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("w")]
    public ResponseTags[] warnings { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("i")]
    public ResponseTags[] informations { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string value { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("datatype")]
    public DataType datatype { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("group")]
    public Group[] groups { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class DataType
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("field")]
    public Field[] fields { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ResponseTags
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string value { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string path { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string HL7ErrorCode { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string SegmentID { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FieldPosition { get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FieldRepetition { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ComponentNumber { get; set;}
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string SubComponentNumber { get; set;}
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Severity { get; set; }
}
```

Then the object is being populated by some xml deserialization

```
private Message getMessage(string xml)
    {
        if (xml.Length == 0)
            return new Message();
        XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
        MemoryStream soapwriter = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
        return (Message)serial.Deserialize(soapwriter);
    }
```

And here is some test xml, there is no real data in here, I have scraped that out

```
<message xmlns="" type="VxuV04">
    <segment type="msh">
        <field name="MSH-1 (FieldSeperator)">
            <![CDATA[ | ]]>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-2 (EncodingCharacters)">
            <![CDATA[ ^~\& ]]>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-3 (SendingApplication)">
            <datatype type="hd">
                <field name="NamespaceID">OMG IMMUNIZATIO</field>
                <field name="UniversalID"/>
                <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-4 (SendingFacility)">
            <datatype type="hd">
                <field name="NamespaceID">FF0000</field>
                <field name="UniversalID"/>
                <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-5 (ReceivingApplication)">
            <datatype type="hd">
                <field name="NamespaceID">AK TEST FACILITY</field>
                <field name="UniversalID"/>
                <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-6 (ReceivingFacility)">
            <datatype type="hd">
                <field name="NamespaceID">ML1001</field>
                <field name="UniversalID"/>
                <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
                <group type="ProblemCollection">
                    <e value="Invalid value: ML1001. Reason: No user assigned to this facility." path="MSH/ReceivingFacility/NamespaceID" type="problem" HL7ErrorCode="103" HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription="Table value not found" SegmentID="Msh" SegmentSequence="" FieldPosition="6" FieldRepetition="1" ComponentNumber="" SubComponentNumber="" Severity="E"/>
                </group>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-7 (DateTimeOfMessage)">3/28/2014</field>
        <field name="MSH-9 (MessageType)">
            <datatype type="msg">
                <field name="MessageCode">VXU</field>
                <field name="TriggerEvent">V04</field>
                <field name="MessageStructure">VXU_V04</field>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-10 (MessageControlID)">dsfg00541680</field>
        <field name="MSH-11 (ProcessingID)">
            <datatype type="processingtype">
                <field name="ProcessingID">P</field>
                <field name="ProcessingMode"/>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-12 (HL7Version)">2.5.1</field>
        <field name="MSH-15 (AcceptAcknowledgmentType)"/>
        <field name="MSH-16 (ApplicationAcknowledgmentType)"/>
        <field name="MSH-21 (MessageProfileIdentifier)">
            <datatype type="ei">
                <field name="EntityIdentifier"/>
                <field name="NamespaceID"/>
                <field name="UniversalID"/>
                <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-22 (ResponsibleSendingOrganization)">
            <datatype type="xon">
                <field name="OrganizationName"/>
                <field name="OrganizationNameTypeCode"/>
                <field name="AssigningAuthority">
                    <datatype type="hd">
                        <field name="NamespaceID"/>
                        <field name="UniversalID"/>
                        <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
                    </datatype>
                </field>
                <field name="IdentifierTypeCode"/>
                <field name="AssigningFacility">
                    <datatype type="hd">
                        <field name="NamespaceID"/>
                        <field name="UniversalID"/>
                        <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
                    </datatype>
                </field>
                <field name="OrganizationIdentifier"/>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="MSH-23 (ResponsibleReceivingOrganization)">
            <datatype type="xon">
                <field name="OrganizationName"/>
                <field name="OrganizationNameTypeCode"/>
                <field name="AssigningAuthority">
                    <datatype type="hd">
                        <field name="NamespaceID"/>
                        <field name="UniversalID"/>
                        <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
                    </datatype>
                </field>
                <field name="IdentifierTypeCode"/>
                <field name="AssigningFacility">
                    <datatype type="hd">
                        <field name="NamespaceID"/>
                        <field name="UniversalID"/>
                        <field name="UniversalIDType"/>
                    </datatype>
                </field>
                <field name="OrganizationIdentifier"/>
            </datatype>
        </field>
        <field name="Errors">
            <group type="ProblemCollection">
                <e value="MSH-6 (ReceivingFacility) : Invalid value: zz1001. Reason: No user assigned to this facility." path="MSH/ReceivingFacility/NamespaceID" type="problem" HL7ErrorCode="z3" HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription="Table value not found" SegmentID="Msh" SegmentSequence="" FieldPosition="6" FieldRepetition="1" ComponentNumber="" SubComponentNumber="" Severity="E"/>
            </group>
        </field>
    </segment>  
    <field name="Errors">
        <group type="ProblemCollection">
            <e value="MSH-6 (ReceivingFacility) : Invalid value: ML1001. Reason: No user assigned to this facility." path="MSH/ReceivingFacility/NamespaceID" type="problem" HL7ErrorCode="zzz" HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription="Table value not found" SegmentID="Msh" SegmentSequence="" FieldPosition="6" FieldRepetition="1" ComponentNumber="" SubComponentNumber="" Severity="E"/>
        </group>
    </field>
    <field name="Warnings">
        <group type="ProblemCollection">
            <w value="PID-11 (PatientAddress)-Mailing : County Code  is not in the list of known county codes ." path="PID/PatientAddress" type="problem" HL7ErrorCode="zzz" HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription="Table value not found" SegmentID="Pid" SegmentSequence="" FieldPosition="11" FieldRepetition="" ComponentNumber="" SubComponentNumber="" Severity="W"/>
            <w value="PID-11 (PatientAddress)-Physical : County Code  is not in the list of known county codes ." path="PID/PatientAddress" type="problem" HL7ErrorCode="zzz" HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription="Table value not found" SegmentID="Pid" SegmentSequence="" FieldPosition="11" FieldRepetition="" ComponentNumber="" SubComponentNumber="" Severity="W"/>
        </group>
    </field>
    <field name="ErrorsAndWarningsCombined">
        <group type="ProblemCollection">
            <e value="MSH-6 (ReceivingFacility) : Invalid value: ML1001. Reason: No user assigned to this facility." path="MSH/ReceivingFacility/NamespaceID" type="problem" HL7ErrorCode="zz" HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription="Table value not found" SegmentID="Msh" SegmentSequence="" FieldPosition="6" FieldRepetition="1" ComponentNumber="" SubComponentNumber="" Severity="E"/>
            <w value="PID-11 (PatientAddress)-Mailing : County Code is not in the list of known county codes" path="PID/PatientAddress" type="problem" HL7ErrorCode="zz" HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription="Table value not found" SegmentID="Pid" SegmentSequence="" FieldPosition="11" FieldRepetition="" ComponentNumber="" SubComponentNumber="" Severity="W"/>
            <w value="PID-11 (PatientAddress)-Physical : County Code is not in the list of known county codes ." path="PID/PatientAddress" type="problem" HL7ErrorCode="zzz" HL7ErrorCodeFullDescription="Table value not found" SegmentID="Pid" SegmentSequence="" FieldPosition="z" FieldRepetition="" ComponentNumber="" SubComponentNumber="" Severity="W"/>
        </group>
    </field>
</message>
```

I promise the closing message tag is there

Comment: I don't know much about Linq, so I'll refrain from answering, but I don't see any issues with this kind of abstraction. In fact, I think it's a good thing.

Comment: That is what I was thinking but there are some dev's that have been deving for years and they seem to break everything out into methods.  I feel like this way is cleaner.

Comment: Though, consider replacing `Issues.Where(x => x.name == "XXX").Count() > 0` with `Issues.Any(x => x.name == "XXX")`. Still LINQ, but much more concise.

Comment: The `.Any()` is more efficient as well as it stops after finding the first result whereas `.Count()` doesn't know what number it's being compared to and has to iterate the entire collection. Other than that, you look good. If you weren't using LINQ, you'd still have to perform the operations that LINQ does to find out if the object has any errors (for example).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think that most things are said, I recapitulate and add some of my own stuff:

- As Jesse said, I'd use `Any` instead of `Where` + `Count`. It should have a better performance, I think.
- Properties are for me: `HasNoIssues`, `HasWarnings` and `HasErrors`
- In my Opinion the rest should be methods
- `Issues.Where(x => x.Name == "Warnings").First()` is the same as `Issues.First(x => x.Name == "Warnings")`
- I changed the names of the functions (but it may be a matter of taste).

So it would be in my approach like this:

```
    public Field[] Issues { get; set; }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            if (HasIssues)
            {
                return Issues.Any(x => x.Name == "Errors");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool HasIssues
    {
        get
        {
            return Issues != null && Issues.Length > 0;
        }
    }

    public bool HasWarnings
    {
        get
        {
            if (HasIssues)
            {
                return Issues.Any(x => x.Name == "Warnings");
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public ResponseTags[] GetErrors()
    {
        if (HasErrors)
        {
            return Issues.First(x => x.Name == "Errors").Groups.First().Warnings;
        }
        return new ResponseTags[0];
    }

    public ResponseTags[] GetWarnings()
    {
        if (HasWarnings)
        {
            return Issues.First(x => x.Name == "Warnings").Groups.First().Warnings;
        }
        return new ResponseTags[0];
    }

    // For the display functions:
    // I don't understand why you only usses the first
    // groups of errors and warnings, but that may be a requirement.

    public string GetErrorsDisplayData()
    {
        var errorString = "";
        if (HasErrors)
        {
            errorString += Issues.First(x => x.Name == "Errors")
                .Groups.First()
                .Errors.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + t.Value + "\n");
        }
        return errorString;
    }

    public string GetWarningsDisplayData()
    {
        var warningString = "";
        if (HasWarnings)
        {
            warningString += Issues.First(x => x.Name == "Warnings")
                .Groups.First()
                .Warnings.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + t.Value + "\n");
        }
        return warningString;
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest `HasIssues` is better than `HasNoIssues` for consistency and to avoid double negatives in code like `if (!HasNoIssues)`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edit the code.

Answer (score 15):

Methods `Set` and `Get` Properties through their `Get` and `Set` methods, so it isn't a really good idea to perform operations on properties inside their get and set methods.

you should use the object methods to do this.

> ```
> public string DisplayErrors
> {
>     get
>     {
>         var errorString = "";
>         if (HasErrors)
>         {
>             errorString += Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Errors").First().groups.First().errors.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + t.value+"\n");
>         }
>         return errorString;
>
>     }
> }
> ```

should be like this

```
public string DisplayErrors (bool inputBoolean)
{
    var errorString = "";
    if (inputBoolean)
    {
         errorString += Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Errors").First().groups.First().errors.Aggregate("", (data, t) => data + t.value+"\n");
    }
    return errorString;
}

Console.WriteLine(DisplayErrors(HasErrors));
```

`DisplayErrors` is an action to me, so it should be a method that the object performs not a property of the object,

- Property = description
- Method = Action

---

Look at what is in the `HasWarnings` property.  A boolean property should be an object flag that is set to true or false, a method inside the object can get or set the flag (to either true or false) or it can be visible to something interacting with the object.

All of this makes me think over the whole piece of code,  if I create a new object all of these properties are referring to other properties nothing is set.

`Warnings` property looks at `HasWarnings` property which in turn looks at `HasNoIssues` property (which really should be something like `HasIssues`) inside of a class called `Issues` , it has Issues.

This isn't a completed, working class, if you develop it farther you should see that this isn't a good design at all

`HasWarnings` should be a property, but it shouldn't look to another property for it's value.

There needs to be a constructor that sets the basic properties, this is where you say

```
if (HasIssues) {
    HasWarnings = Issues.Where(x => x.name == "Warnings").Count() > 0;
} else {
    HasWarnings = false;
}
```

Comment: I like what you have with `HasWarnings` as you're basically saying "Does this object have warnings?" whereas the `DisplayErrors` is telling it to do something (display the errors). If you named the property "Errors", then that'd drop it further into a gray area.

Comment: Yeah this is just a snippet from the entire class.  It is an object I have created to be created from some xml that is being parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as `Issues` is a fixed size array, personally I'd be looking into caching the results (unless `Issues` or things within the `Issues` will be changing more than the properties are being called).

Though if your class is being populated with de-serialisation and it's not supposed to be changed (as I'd assume it is given the class' name), I'd be tempted to make it publicly immutable by setting all the setters to private/protected. This would have the additional benefit of meaning you could evaluate the properties at the point of de-serialisation and not have to query the arrays from within properties at all.

Comment: All of the arrays are now lists.

Comment: @DeadlyChambers In which case I'd suggest using IList<T>/ICollection<T> for the external representation since it means you can swap out the class being used internally and it won't break the external interface.